# What is the millisecond rate that robot-create can respond to two different drive commands?

Tags: irobot-create

I want to issue two slightly different drive commands what is the smallest loop rate that the robot-create accepts new commands?

I know from reading the documentation that it appears the sensors are read every 15ms.

Not sure what the command rate is?

Answer (score 1):

The command rate should be the same as the sensors (so ~15 ms)